# Subdifferential of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, non-smooth-analysis

I am a beginner in functional analysis. Recently, I came across the term "subdifferential" of a convex function. I would like to know the notion of subdifferential of a convex function in detail (or some references). In particular, if a real valued convex function has minimum value $0$ at $0$, then how to explain it using the subdifferential of that function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defintion, subdifferential $\partial f(x_0)$ of $f(x)$ at point $x_0$ consists of vectors $v$ such that
$f(x) - f(x_0) \geq (v, x-x_0)$ for all $x \in X$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes dot product. If $x^*$ is [argmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max#Arg_min) of $f(x)$, then $\forall x \in X :f(x) \geq f(x^*) \Leftrightarrow f(x) - f(x^*) \geq 0 = (0, x - x^*)$, so $0 \in \partial f(x^*)$.

Moreover, the opposite statement is also true: if $0 \in \partial f(x^*)$, then $f(x) \geq f(x^*)$ for all $x \in X$, so $f$ has minimum at $x^*$.

Comment: Thank you @Yalikesifulei. Since you mentioned dot product, I would like to ask is it only valid in the setting of inner product space and not in general normed linear space? Also, I do not understand argmin. It would be so nice, if you elaborate this in more detail.

Comment: Argmin is a set of points (or just one point), such that $f$ has minimum at all of them. For example, if $f(x) = x^2$, $\mathrm{argmin} f(x) = \{0\}$ and for $f(x) = x^4 - x^2$ $\mathrm{argmin} f(x) = \{\pm \sqrt{2}/2\}$.

To be honest, I've never heard about subdifferential calculus in general normed spaces.

Comment: Thank you @Yalikesifulei, for your explanations. However, my whole question is in context of normed linear spaces.

Comment: In case of normed spaces, I think, $v$ is not a vector, but element of $X^*$ - it is bounded linear functional, and all explanations should be the same.

Comment: Thankyou @Yalikesifulei

Comment: So basically you are assuming the domain of $f$ to be an inner product space.